# How a Virtualbox ubuntu VM able to resolve another ubuntu VM's hostname.?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox, ipv6, hostname

I have 2 Virtualbox VM's on which I have Ubuntu 15.

The hostnames are:

- Machine 1: *satya-VirtualBox*
- Machine 2: *sam1-VirtualBox*

Hosts file on machine 1-

[image: VM 1]

But I am able to ping machine 2 from 1 using *hostname* without any DNS server in my environment. How is the *hostname* getting resolved?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Ubuntu machines are using [Multicast DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast_DNS).